# class in R is changed from data.frame to character after deleting certain rows

Tags: r

I am trying to import a pdf file into R so I can work with the data.

```
text_ira <- pdf_text('./data/IRA-June2012-2020.pdf') %>% 
    str_split('\n') %>% 
    unlist()

ira <- data.frame(text = text_ira) %>% 
    filter(
        str_starts(text, '0') |
        str_starts(text, '1'))
```

when I type class(ira) it shows a data.frame.

But when I hit the command below (I only have 110 rows in the ira data frame):

```
ira <- ira[-c(1000),]
```

when I then type class(ira) it shows a character.  Can someone please explain why that is?

I need it to show as a character in order to proceed.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? Either share the output of `text_ira` or make an example which you are able to share.

Comment: The last command coerces to vector as `drop = TRUE`. you need `ira[-1000, , drop = FALSE]`

Comment: if you include `as_tibble()` somewhere you won't need `drop=FALSE`

Comment: Thanks, everyone for your quick response.  I think the `drop = TRUE` makes sense.